# IMvxTouchModalHost not resolvable when using custom presenter

Tags: ios, mvvmcross

I've created a custom service which needs a reference to my custom presenter, but I get an error on resolving IMvxTouchModalHost. By using the default MvxTouchViewPresenter, everything works fine.

Here is my code:

AppDelegate.cs

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        this.window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        var presenter = new AppViewPresenter(this, this.window);

        var setup = new Setup(this, presenter);
        setup.Initialize();

        Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>().Start();

        this.window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
    }
```

AppViewPresenter.cs

```
public class AppViewPresenter : MvxTouchViewPresenter
{
    private IMvxTouchViewCreator viewCreator;
    protected IMvxTouchViewCreator ViewCreator
    {
        get { return this.viewCreator ?? (this.viewCreator = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTouchViewCreator>()); }
    }

    public AppViewPresenter(IUIApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window)
        : base(applicationDelegate, window)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnMasterNavigationControllerCreated()
    {
        this.MasterNavigationController.WeakDelegate = new NavigationControllerDelegate();
    }

    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        var nextViewController = (UIViewController)this.ViewCreator.CreateView(request);
        if (nextViewController is IMvxModalTouchView)
        {
            nextViewController.TransitioningDelegate = new NavigationControllerTransitioningDelegate();
            nextViewController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom;
            this.CurrentTopViewController.PresentViewController(nextViewController, true, null);
        }
        else
        {
            base.Show(request);
        }

        if (request.PresentationValues != null)
        {
            if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey("ClearStack") && this.CurrentTopViewController != null)
            {
                if (this.CurrentTopViewController.GetType() != nextViewController.GetType())
                {
                    this.MasterNavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override void Close(IMvxViewModel toClose)
    {
        if (this.CurrentTopViewController.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            this.CurrentTopViewController.DismissModalViewController(true);
        }
        else
        {
            base.Close(toClose);
        }
    }
}
```

Setup.cs

```
public class Setup : MvxTouchSetup
{
    public Setup(MvxApplicationDelegate appDelegate, IMvxTouchViewPresenter presenter)
        : base(appDelegate, presenter)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new App.Core.Infrastructure.App();
    }

    protected override IMvxTouchViewsContainer CreateTouchViewsContainer()
    {
        return new AppViewContainer();
    }

    protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);

        registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(typeof(MvxUIPageControlCurrentPageTargetBinding), typeof(UIPageControl),
                                           "CurrentPage");


    }
}
```

CustomService.cs

```
public class CustomService : BaseService, ICustomService
{
    private readonly IMvxTouchModalHost modalHost;

    public CustomService()
    {
        this.modalHost = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTouchModalHost>();
    }
}
```

Exception is thrown in ctor of CustomService:

```
Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to resolve parameter for parameter window of type UIWindow when creating App.Infrastructure.AppViewPresenter

  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.GetIoCParameterValues (System.Type type, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo firstConstructor) [0x0006e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x00031] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.IocConstruct (System.Type t) [0x00006] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxLazySingletonCreator.get_Instance () [0x00020] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxTypeExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass49.<RegisterAsLazySingleton>b__48 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer+ConstructingSingletonResolver.Resolve () [0x00028] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.InternalTryResolve (System.Type type, IResolver resolver, System.Object& resolved) [0x00042] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.InternalTryResolve (System.Type type, Nullable1 requiredResolverType, System.Object& resolved) [0x0002e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.InternalTryResolve (System.Type type, System.Object& resolved) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve (System.Type t) [0x00011] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve[T] () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.Resolve[TService] () [0x00006] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at App.Services.CustomService..ctor () [0x00009] in c:\Src\App\iPhone\Services\CustomService.cs:24
```

Comment: Can you format the exception and add a call stack for it?

Comment: I'm sorry but that call stack makes no sense to me and it's also not obvious who is creating CustomService... are you sure your code isn't registering `IMvxTouchModalHost` with IoC somewhere in some funky way?

Comment: I'm sure. If I switch to MvxTouchViewPresenter and do not change something else, everything is fine. CustomService is only constructed via Mvx.Resolve<ICustomService>()

Comment: And: There is only one usage of IMvxTouchModalHost: Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTouchModalHost>() in ctor of CustomService

Comment: What's you Setup.cs look like? Does it do some funky auto-registration? (Or  does anything else do some auto-registration on the Assembly containing your Presenter?)

Comment: Added code of Setup.cs to the question. There is nothing funky, I think. At runtime, Presenter-Property is set to AppViewPresenter, seems to be good.
Also re-registering Presenter via RegisterPresenter() changes nothing

Comment: It's the only explanation I can see... try overriding `protected override void InitializeIoC() { base.InitializeIoC(); Mvx.CallbackWhenRegistered<IMvxTouchModalHost>(() => { var putABreakpointHere = 0; }); }` - just look at the call stack when the callback gets hit... If the first callback isn't suspicious then you will maybe need to tweak this debug code to reregister for callbacks to see what registers it again... (alternatively register your own custom ioc container to debug intercept the registrations).

Comment: Didn't see something strange. It is registered by Setup.Initialize() and it is of type AppViewPresenter. What do you think? Somewhere is an reregistration with another type, not AppViewPresenter?

Comment: IMvxTouchModalHost is registered twice - both by Setup.Initialize(). I think this is whats done by RegisterPresenter() in MvxTouchSetup.cs, isn't it?

Comment: When it's registered, then immediately try resolving it - I bet you get it back no problems... assuming you do, then register another callback - that should detect if something else is registering it with a lazy constructor - your exception callstack tells us that something else is... (heading offline now anyways. zzzz here)

Comment: You are right - I got it back without any exception... now I am searching for the reregistration.

Comment: My guess: look in the auto-registration code - the stuff that automatically registers types by interfaces... (you can probably test this theory by making your `AppViewPresenter` type internal to see if it hides it - or by adding a new `IFoo` interface to the presenter - does that `IFoo` also get auto-registered somehow?)

Comment: I'm confused.

`var foo = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTouchModalHost>();

            this.CreatableTypes()
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

            var bar = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTouchModalHost>();`

foo is AppViewPresenter, bar throws Exception.

this.CreatableTypes().AsInterfaces() returns only one item, where ServiceType is IMvxTouchModalHost - it's implementation is AppViewPresenter.

Registration in Core.App.cs is done via `this.CreatableTypes()
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();`

Comment: That sure looks like some funky auto-registration stuff to me. It looks like you are choosing to register all public types by their interfaces (and I'm guessing you are running this on the assembly containing your presenter). `I'm confused` - why? What do you not understand about that code? I think `this.CreatableTypes() .AsInterfaces() .RegisterAsLazySingleton();` is pretty easy to read? And it's different by one line to the default code template - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/nuspec/CoreContent/App.cs.pp#L9

Comment: My confusion has gone, it is pretty easy to read but I didn't see this missing line. :-O

Thanks Stuart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I accidently removed .EndingWith("Service") in service registration.
So, in App.cs there must be, of course, any filter for registration. Otherwise it reregisters everything. So, changed registration from

```
this.CreatableTypes().AsInterfaces().RegisterAsLazySingleton();
```

to e.g.

```
this.CreatableTypes().EndingWith("Service").AsInterfaces().RegisterAsLazySingleton();
```

solved it.